# Django admin. Поменять url приложения на кастомный

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

В джанго проекте есть приложение user. В админке адрес у него такой 0.0.0.0:8000/admin/user. Можно ли изменить этот url допустим на 0.0.0.0:8000/admin/users не меняя названия приложения "user"?

Comment: «апликухи» — это что, простите?

Comment: @IgorR. исправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли это возможно, джанго автоматически мапит урлы по названию приложений. Если будете менять название приложения, то советую создать новое и перенести всё туда.

Comment: Да, я тоже не нашел ничего к сожалению. Придется переименовывать.

Comment: @Xoma163 Возможно, но придётся много чего переопределить в `AdminSite`

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0, не есть бест практис